# Reconocer caracteres de LaTeX con Lex

Tags: c, flex, bison, yacc

Estoy intentando reconocer caracteres de LaTeX como '\to' '\neg' y solo imprimir eso o hacer que Lex los reconozca. Intenté con [\a-zA-Z]+ pero obviamente me reconoce todo lo que inicie con un backslash. No he encontrado alguna forma de quizás hacer más especifica la búsqueda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El patrón es `\\[a-zA-Z]+`.

Como en C, `\a` el control con código \0x07 ("alarma"), así que `\a-z` incluye todos los caracteres con códigos entre 0x07 y 0x7A (`z`), que claramente no es lo que quisieras.

Además, es importante entender que `[...]` es un conjunto de caracteres, que aplique a un solo carácter a la vez. Si quieres describir algo seguido por otro, ponles en seguida. P.ej, `ab` es una `a` seguida por una `b`, mientras `[ab]` es un carácter que podría ser o `a` o `b`.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Entonces si quisiera solo encontrar un \to debería ser algo como \\to sin los []?

Comment: @sergio: Así es. La documentación en inglés: https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns. Hay descripciones de expresiones regulares en castellano --lo de [es.wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresi%C3%B3n_regular#Los_corchetes_%22[_]%22) es aceptable-- pero hay que cuidar con flex porque tiene sus particularidades

Comment: Y otra cosa: `\\to` encuentra `\to` no importa que sigue. P.ej. encuentra el `\to` que empieza `\tonteria`. Lo normal es poner las reglas específicas primero y despues la general `\\[a-zA-Z]+` para evitar que una regla específica encuentra un prefijo. Flex siempre usa la regla que más encuentra; si dos son iguales, usa la que aparece primera. Por eso, las específicas primeras, y la general al final.